# How to use SystemMediaTransportControls with Electron?

Tags: windows, electron

I'm building a wrapper app over a website with music. And I want to add this media control `SystemMediaTransportControls`[image]

I added `@nodert-win10/windows.media` and `@nodert-win10/windows.media.playback` dependencies to my project. I found a [code](https://github.com/MarshallOfSound/Google-Play-Music-Desktop-Player-UNOFFICIAL-/blob/da99d1a5dbd681bbe447bfa04ac659705790da12/src/renderer/windows/GPMWebView/playback/systemMediaService/win10.js) that, as I understand, can do it, but I don't know how to make this element apper. What am I missing? Here is my code:

```
const { MediaPlaybackStatus, MediaPlaybackType }= require('@nodert-win10/windows.media');
const { BackgroundMediaPlayer } = require('@nodert-win10/windows.media.playback');

const Controls = BackgroundMediaPlayer.current.systemMediaTransportControls;
Controls.isChannelDownEnabled = false;
Controls.isChannelUpEnabled = false;
Controls.isFastForwardEnabled = false;
Controls.isNextEnabled = true;
Controls.isPauseEnabled = true;
Controls.isPlayEnabled = true;
Controls.isPreviousEnabled = true;
Controls.isRecordEnabled = false;
Controls.isRewindEnabled = false;
Controls.isStopEnabled = true;
Controls.playbackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.closed;
Controls.displayUpdater.type = MediaPlaybackType.music;
Controls.displayUpdater.musicProperties.title = 'TestTitle';
Controls.displayUpdater.musicProperties.arti
```

and in track changes handler:

```
Controls.playbackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.playing;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working, but I was using multimedia keys shortcuts with module [globalShortcuts](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/global-shortcut) and because of that this element didn't appear.

Comment: Hate to leave a comment on such a old post, but I cannot get this to work. I've tried called the function manually as a test and nothing works. What's the main thing that gets it to pop up on the screen?

Comment: @ErraticFox You just need to initialize it with code that I left in the description and that's it. When you click on multimedia keys it will appear. As I understand it has it's own subscribers to multimedia keys so you shouldn't implement any of it on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. As for the "When you click on multimedia keys it will appear" could you link me to the documentation? As you said, I don't think it works. As I put `Controls.playbackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.playing;` in a setTimeout and it didn't do anything.

Comment: UPDATE: FINALLY, do you mind if I edit your answer with the code snippet as an example?

Comment: @ErraticFox yes, please do so